# How to paste embedded hyperlinks into the TRichViewEdit control?

Tags: delphi

When I copy an embedded hyperlink from Outlook or Notepad++ and paste it into a `TRichViewEdit`, it shows the hyperlink format like [embedded](http://foo.bar).

I tried to debug the `TRichViewEdit` and searched a lot on Google but couldn't find a solution.

When I call `Clipboard.AsText` I get only the hyperlink(http://foo.bar). How can I get the text of the embedded hyperlink, not the embedded address? Is there something like "hidden data" or do I have to do something else?

Comment: "the text of the embedded hyperlink" Do you mean the text of the document which is the target of the hyperlink?

Comment: With `Clipboard.AsText` i get the Target address like http://foo.bar. But i want to have the Text "over" the address. The Hyperlinks are copied from Outlook. At the sample: <a href="http://foo.bar"> embedded</a>, i want to get the word 'embedded' and not only the hyperlink.

Comment: I don't have TRichView component but is this it: [http://www.trichview.com/features/trichview.html](http://www.trichview.com/features/trichview.html) If so a quick look at the online documentation and I came across this method `OnReadHyperlink` see here: [http://www.trichview.com/help/index.html?idh_trichview_onreadhyperlink.html](http://www.trichview.com/help/index.html?idh_trichview_onreadhyperlink.html) Maybe it can help?